# Is it possible to search text within large PDF documents in SharePoint Online like we can in Google Books?

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, pdf

We have quite a few training and tutorial documents in large pdf files (over 700 pages). SharePoint Online does a satisfactory job in crawling through these pdf documents but does it also crawl the page number along with the text its located on?
What I am aiming for is the Google Books' search experience on SharePoint. Any help and advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it also crawls the page number of PDF files. In the below screenshot(unfortunately in Dutch), we can see the PDF preview opening in Word Online showing the page number.

Here, Pagina = Page. In my PDF document, there are 19 pages, so its previewing the 1st page of 19 pages.

[image]